# Execute Sync report api not giving correct result

Tags: integration, profile, permission-sets, namedcredentials, reports-api

We are using named credentials to call **execute sync api(POST)** call (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_getreportrundata.htm). Issue is that we get report aggregate data when the callout executes from Admin user but for non-admin user it gives 0 result. Following are more data points related to this issue:

1. Named credentials(legacy) is authenticated by the same admin user
2. The reports are accessible to non-admin user. In fact we create a **report url** after making callouts. The **url** redirects to the report result with desired data in the context of non-admin user
3. READ access is already provided for object UserExternalCredential object through permission set
4. In the callout we are sending a **dynamic value** to already defined report filter in report metadata request.
5. **The named credential is not available to add in profiles/permission set. It is "Named Principal" type so this is also something what we are not able to explain.**
6. The callout executes from **Apex class**( controller for LWC)

**P.S. This works correctly when we run the callout through the admin user or more specifically, the user who authenticated the named credential.**